# Existence of Green functions and some properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, asymptotics, green-function

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$， $N\geq 3$, $p\in \Omega$ is a fixed point, $\lambda$ is a parameter (can be 0,>0,<0),  if there exisits a Green function $G_{\lambda}(x,p)$ such that
$$(-\Delta_{x} -\lambda)G_{\lambda}(x,p)=\delta_p, \quad \text{ in }\, \Omega, \quad G_{\lambda}(x,p)=0\quad \text{ on }\, \partial \Omega,$$
where $\delta_p$ is a Dirac function at $p$.
If so,what are the properties of such function $G_{\lambda}(x,p)$, like positivity and bounds estimate, and asymptotic behavior  like $G_{\lambda}(x,p)\to  G_{0}(x,p)$  when $\lambda\to 0$? Any comments and references are welcome!

Comment: Dow does $G_\lambda$ depends on $\lambda$? It appears no $\lambda$ in your problem.

Comment: @MicheleCaselli Sorry, I have corrected the typos.